# Splunk: find what a user is searching for?

Tags: splunk, splunk-query

I am trying to write a Splunk SPL query that will show me the most popular search terms that a user is looking for in one of my web apps. I have the logs already in Splunk but I am having a hard time extract the search parameter from the event. The event shows the full SQL select statement that looks like the query below:

```
select result from table where search_term = 'searched for this text'
```

How can I have this:

```
index=my_app search_term | top result
```

How do I actually capture the search term?

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You can use `rex` to extract the search term.  Something like this

```
index=my_app | rex "search_term = '(?<search_term>[^']+)"
```

If you want individual words then use the `split` function followed by `mvexpand` to make each word a separate event.

```
... | eval words=split(search_term, " ") | mvexpand words
```